# iOS - Does Core Data Have A "Created_At" Timestamp?

Tags: ios, core-data

I just started learning about and using `Core Data` in my app. Whenever I fetch a list of my saved object, I want to make sure that I ALSO delete the objects that have been in `Core Data` for longer than a week (will be less when I'm testing, obviously).

How do I get this done? Do these model objects already have an attribute like "createdAt" by default like when other databases give default values like "created_at" and "updated_at"?

If not, I'm thinking of adding a "createdAt" attribute of type `Date` to my data model, but I'm still kind of confused on how to delete objects that are older than one week after fetching them from `Core Data`.

Any help or advice would be appreciated, as I am still new to using this powerful tool. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Core Data does not automatically create any data for you.  That is business logic.  If you want a `created_at` property in your entity, add it and set it in the `awakeFromInsert` method in your `NSManagedObject` subclass.  You can also set it externally to the object at creation time but putting it in the `awakeFromInsert` tends to be more consistent.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like a lot of reading I'll have to do in the Apple Developer Docs